# how to invoke an internal void method?

Tags: c#, internal

How to invoke RefreshMethod of base(Aclass) where Aclass is not instantiable.

```
public class Aclass
{
private Aclass();
internal void RefreshMethod();
}

public class Bclass:Aclass
{
//I want to invoke RefreshMethod... How to do it ? Thanks,if you have any idea?
}
```

Comment: If you cannot create AClass there, maybe RefreshMethod should be static?

Comment: `Bclass : Bclass` is invalid. Did you mean `Bclass : Aclass`? It would really help if you'd post a valid example.

Comment: You are not inheriting from AClass in this code

Answer (score 1):

Since `RefreshMethod` is **not** a static mehtod, you have to instantiate an object of type `AClass` and then invoke it as usual.

However, I don't think that actually this is your problem. I think that `public Bclass:Bclass` is a typo error. You might wanted to write the following:

```
public Bclass: Aclass
{

}
```

Then since `BClass` inherits `AClass` you can invoke `RefreshMethod` in your `BClass`.